# Second alias listed as "other" cannot be used for login?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

I'm loosing access to my university email account and in the process of switching everything to use my gmail email as a username (I have no wish to actually log in with my google account).

I'm not sure how it happened but my @gmail email is listed under aliases when it did not used to be (its what I wanted but I'm not sure how it happened as I had not added it yet), and when I try to login with it, I am told that I do not have the right password. When I recover my password it defaults to my @university email address and I still cannot login with my gmail email.

When I reset my password, this is the email I got (at my gmail account as I have set that as the "contact" email):

```
We received an account recovery request on Super User for email@gmail.com.
If you initiated this request, click this link to reset your password.

As a reminder, you can use any of the following credentials to log in to your account:
Email and Password (email@university.com)
email@gmail.com
Note: once logged in, you can review existing credentials and add new ones by 
visiting your profile, clicking Edit Profile & Settings and My Logins.

If you did not initiate this account recovery request, just ignore this email. 
We'll keep your account safe.
```

How can I login with my gmail email address? (How can I assign that email a password as it does not seem to accept my normal password)

(I did search around this meta site to see if I could find an answer but had no luck...)

Answer (score 3):

Your Google email was used as a notification email in your preferences - you never created a SE OpenID for it and thus cannot login using that method. It's listed as "other" because it's literally just a verified email. It's never been used as a login method and thus isn't categorized as a specific service.

However, being attached as a verified email has its advantages. If you [created an SE OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/) at any point and attempted to create a profile with it, the new profile would automatically get merged into the existing account and that OpenID would get attached because both accounts would now have the same VerifiedEmail address attached to them. The same would happen if you attempted to login using the Google button with the same account. You could then use those extra credentials to continue logging into your account.

**Note:** The merge may not be instantaneous. Certain conditions can cause auto-merge to fail and drop into a queue for manual review. The merge wouldn't take effect until the request was approved. If it's taking too long, feel free to [contact us](/contact) and ask for the profiles to be merged via the "other" option.